# Configuring network share over VPN

Tags: router, windows-10, vpn, ftp, openvpn

I have created an OpenVPN server on my [Asus RT-AC87U router](http://event.asus.com/2012/nw/dummy_ui/en/).
There is an external drive connected to it, serving as an ftp server.

I have a client connecting over OpenVPN from another country and I wanted it to be able to access my external share on a secure connection.

After configuring the client PC (Windows 10) over TeamViewer for OpenVPN, I have created a network share on it using `192.168.1.1` as the ftp server local IP address.

Everything was working as expected besides one thing that I can't understand.
After I have disconnected the the OpenVPN client (also checked the router menu and it said `Disconnected`), the share was still reachable on the client PC and I could access all my files just as before.

Tried the same thing over browser, and it was working as expected after disconnecting the VPN, the ftp is no longer reachable.

My questions:

1. Does this method secure the connection?
2. Why is the share still reachable if the OpenVPN client is disconnected?

Comment: local cache copy of the remote directory on the PC that thinks it's attached?   Try getting a significant data when it is unconnected

Comment: @infixed - yup, you were right, if you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may actually be disconnected, but you can't tell if you are looking at data already locally cached.  Like of a directory you looked at while connected.

If you try to access a significant of data you didn't access before disconnect, it should fail